# Using Tail Recursively in Linux to Output into Individually Files

Tags: linux, recursion, find

I am trying to recursively (with sub-directories) read the last line of each file of a certain type (*.log) and write the output into individual files for each of the *.log files

e.g. (tail_"filename").

The closest bit of code I've been able to piece together is the following. I would need to send the information to a file for each of the instances it runs the tail command however.

```
find -type f | while read filename; do tail -1 $filename; done
```

Comment: If an example file is dir1/dir2/file.txt - what would the path of the corresponding tail file be?

Comment: @user3490469: please edit your question to improve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there with your solution. Just add the `> ${f}.tail` to create the tail file:

```
find . -type f | while read f;do tail -1 $f > ${f}.tail;done
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility might be

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c "tail -1 '{}' > '{}'.tail"  \;
```